# Deploy rails app to digital ocean cap aborted! issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment, capistrano

I am trying to deploy my rails app on digital ocean.
I am following [Deploying a Rails App on Ubuntu 14.04 with Capistrano, Nginx, and Puma](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma#normal-deployments)

its my first time to deploy an app so it took more than a day to reach on 7th step

But now when I put `cap production deploy:initial` in terminal
it gives the following error

```
DEBUG [63cf0a07] Running [ -d ~/.rvm ] on 162.243.10.38
DEBUG [63cf0a07] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError: agent could not sign data with requested identity

Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: The problem seems to be related to SSH keys. Did you add your public key to `authorized_keys` on remote machine?